# firebase apikey is missing or invalid in react native android

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

I'm trying to connect firebase first time with my react-native application but facing an issue which is that:
**Error: Missing or invalid FirebaseOptions property 'apiKey'.** I try to search to solve that problem but it doesn't solve.

```
import Firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app'
useEffect(()=>{
 Firebase.initializeApp()
},[])
```

```
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
    }
```

Now according to my searches i do the following things to solve it

1. clean my android gradlew
2. Reinstall the node modules
3. Change the google-services:4.3.10 ->4.3.0
4. Redownload the google-serives.json file

but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this helps, but I noticed you don't seem to be configuring Firebase.

This is older code from a prior project where I used Firebase (keys changed for anonymity).

Please note:

```
  //Configure Firebase
  var app = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBA-nJOSHcALkHfR7D7GsBqzU5qmCHY_WA",
    authDomain: "project-e6136.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://project-e6136.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "project-e6136",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "948984656115"
  });
```

I think you need to pass an object into the `initializeApp()`, with your keys.

In my case, I setup these keys at `https://firebase.google.com/`, when I registered an account.

Hopefully this helps, or please comment, if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: its for firebase webapp, but i'm using firebase android app